# set's membership seems not to work (python)

Tags: set, membership

I am working on a image search algorithm that finds certain shapes of certain colors; to save time I only register half of the shape's perimeter in 2 distinct sets, one for the rows and one for the columns used by the shape. The idea is that whenever I find a point which has the target color, I then check if this point's row and column are in a master set (which have both the previous sets); if they are I skip it, if they are not then I initialize 2 recursive fuctions that register the first row and the first column of the shape.

Since it's for a school project, my images are specially tailored

and the code would be

```
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if img[y][x] == target:
            if y in master_set and x in master_set:
                continue
            else:
                row = set()
                column = set()
                flood_fillv2_y(img,x,y,target,column)
                flood_fillv2_x(img,x,y,target,row)
                row=frozenset(row)
                column=frozenset(column)
                master_set.add(row)
                master_set.add(column)
```

The idea then is to check the len of `master_set` to see how many shapes I have, but as I said what I get is that y and x are never in the master set so it keeps doing it for all points of the shape, resulting in a wrong number.

Comment: You seem to be adding `frozenset(row)` and `frozenset(column)` to your master set. So your master set contains frozensets. But you are looking for `x` and `y`, which are ints, not frozensets. Maybe you need to add the **elements** of your `row` and `column` sets to `master_set`, instead of frozenset versions of them.

Comment: yes, i do this because in a previous version instead of ints i added tuples and it seemed to work, so i thought "why not making a set of each part of the tuple".
"Maybe you need to add the elements of your row and column sets to master_set, instead of frozenset versions of them", but if i do that i would be adding pixels, which are all the same and it would trigger the search function

Comment: Adding tuples would make sense, since presumably the difference between `x` and `y` does matter if they are coordinates. But looking for ints inside a set that contains frozensets of ints simply won't work, and I don't think it has any benefit anyway.

Comment: ah i see, a shame then; you see when i used tuple i had to modify my recursive fuction to register in set all the points of the shape, resulting in a stack overflow so i was trying to avoid that entirely by doing this. Thank you for your answers anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer without seeing the whole code, but I can give a guess:

`master_set.add(row)` literally adds the frozenset `row` to the `master_set`, but you probably want *all elements* from the set to be added to `master_set`. Take a look at the `update()` method of sets.

Does this help?

Comment: i thought about this but since i am using ints, i could have repeting numbers, and that could be a problem, i need to think more about this, thank you!